# Did Trevor Reznik really go to the amusement park?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-machinist

In [The Machinist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machinist), we see Trevor Reznik go to the amusement park with Maria (the waitress) and Nicholas (her son). Trevor and Nicholas go on the Route 666 ride, and Nicholas has an epileptic fit.

Later, we find out that

> Nicholas was the young boy that Trevor knocked down and killed, and that Maria was never his waitress at the airport - he hallucinated both in his guilt. However, this scene sets up Trevor to remember more "ghostly" memories, and triggers his deteriorating relationship with both Maria and his other love interest, so it's clearly pivotal in his reconciliation.

So, this begs the question: did Trevor really go to the amusement park? If he did, who did he go with, if anyone? Did he go on the ride, or was it a figment of his imagination?

Comment: Guess we have to look for an interview of the director  or writer so we can know for sure... this kind of questions don't come out of the movie alone, this events could be totally or partially hallucinated.

Comment: The park was real, he might've went alone..
Since all was his hallucinations (like the house of lady, which was actually his own house)...

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt any of that sequence was reality.

It was spurned from the picture of him and his mother at that park, and obviously from the accident itself.  The likelihood that he knew Maria and her son socially before hitting him is a far stretch.

Delusion.